# Server gives 503 on almost all images

Tags: sql-server, wordpress

I have a [Wordpress site](https://team-nord.dk/) there is suddenly getting extremely slow - special on mobile devices. I am often getting this error:

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I checked in my server log and can there is a huge amount of 503 errors: 
[image]
As I understand Wordpress, then everytime you upload a picture there is generated different screensizes. I was looking on my ftp server, and can see each picture is generated with the below sizes:

```
Kajak-i-Norge.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-60x40.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-60x40@2x.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-100x100.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-120x80.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-150x150.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-300x200.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-300x300.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-394x263.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-394x303.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-394x394.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-394x400.jpg
Kajak-i-Norge-600x400.jpg
```

Those 503 errors does that mean the picture is not found on the server?

Comment: Are you using shared hosting?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it is a shared hosting. But the website has been functioning very good for around 2 years without any problems.

Comment: My best guess, based on experience and the info provided, is that the server is being overloaded or is old. You could try using cloudflare to limit bots bogging down the server. Sometimes a server runs smoothly for an extended period of time and then a new website is added to it that has increased traffic or its just old low on resources. I would contact the hosting provider to check on the server health

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have been in a dialog with the hosting provider. I am quite sure that it has nothing to do with them. I still think it have something to do with the pictures there is not getting found when the site loads.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 reasons i think are producing this problem

1 - Something wrong with hosting , especially if your it is shared

2 - Someone trying to do a denial of service

3 - You have a lot of viewers in your server that the server is starting to get gradually slower

Comment: Thank you for the answer and suggestion. I can just commend on them.

1 - I would not say that it matters in this case. I am almost not using any ram or cpu on the server I can see in the control panel. All my other pages with the same host is working perfectly fine..

2 - It is not a DoS attack.

3 - There is between 1 - 3 persons visiting the site pr hour, so not much traffic :-)

Answer (score 0):

The 503 error means that the server can't serve up the image, not that it's not found on the server. 404 errors are not found. The fact that you're seeing both of these errors on your images is most likely the result of server resources being overloaded (as other answers have mentioned)...either capacity or bandwidth. If you're on shared hosting, this can happen often. Your site loaded fine for me just now, but of course, that can change the second your server gets bogged down.

A free cloudflare account is a good recommendation from Dan Web above...it will at least rule out the chance it's spam bots hogging up your resources.

Intermittent issues like this are almost always shared hosting problems. Your host will also rarely accept responsibility for the issues, and you're let with having to decide to move your site to a different hosting solution.